# Excel recalculation order when sorting - how to get it right?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have model code:

```
Dim a(1 To 100) As Integer
Function func1(i As Integer)
    a(Application.Caller.Row) = i
    Debug.Print "func1: " & Application.Caller.Row & " - " & i
    func1 = "value"
End Function
Function func2(r As Range)
    func2 = "other"
    If (a(Application.Caller.Row) > 50) Then
       func2 = "other"
    Else
       func2 = "first"
    End If

   Debug.Print "func2: " & Application.Caller.Row & " - " & a(Application.Caller.Row)
End Function
```

And spreadsheet:

col A col B Col C
51  =func1(A1)  =func2(B1)
9   =func1(A2)  =func2(B2)
8   =func1(A3)  =func2(B3)

[image]

If I sort table using Col C  I get following execution:

func1: 3 - 8
func2: 3 - 8
func1: 2 - 9
func2: 2 - 9
func2: 1 - 8 <-- func2 called before func1, in this case delivering incorect value..
func1: 1 - 51

If I calculate sheet I still get same sequece:

func1: 3 - 8
func2: 3 - 8
func1: 2 - 9
func2: 2 - 9
func2: 1 - 51 <-- func2 called before func1
func1: 1 - 51

Excel 2010 32bit  (sp latest) Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Column C is effectively func2(func1(A)).
As a simple fix, you could define func3() = funct2(func1()), which would eliminate the dependency of C on B?

Comment: that would be an option, just that all point having func1 is that it is very complex function, where func2 displays part of what func1 calculated.. and user wants to see both values same time...

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. Could you perhaps define the main function separately, and then call it for each of func1 and func2?

Comment: so its similar to what you said originally, both func1 and func2 will need to have same parameters, which i want to avoid.